# Chartjs extended doughnut with text tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to build an extended doughnut in chartjs.  I want to display the highest value as percent and its label in the middle. It works fine on load but breaks after an hover event. One a tooltip is being displayed something breaks the first draw event and move the text on the left and i can't figure how to solve this. I made a fiddle to describe this issue :
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3be5zb0v/

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/3be5zb0v/1/

Just add this before your fillText

```
thechart.textAlign = 'start';
```

Comment: The tool tip sets the textAlign and textBaseline values of the 2dContext.  So I needed to also add `thechart.textBaseline = 'alphabetic'` to keep my text from moving vertically.